# Code Fails after catched Exception

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, junit

I am writing a unit test for my Service Class.
I also want to test cases who could not work, then catch the exception and go on. But if i try this the test always fails.

```
    @Before
public void intial() {
    a = new Article();
    a.setName("stock test article");
    articleService.save(a);
    create = new StorageLocation();
    create.setCarlaStorageId(-4636L);
    storageLocationService.save(create);
}

/**
 * Test of save method, of class StockService.
 */
@Test
public void testSave() {
    System.out.println("save");
    Stock save = new Stock();

    // if i do this the test fails, but why ?
//        try {
//            instance.save(save);
//            fail("saved stock without article");
//        } catch (Exception e) {
//            // correct
//            System.out.println("unable to save without article.");
//        }

    save.setArticle(a);
    save.setCntStock(6);
    save.setOldStock(2);

    // if i do this the test fails, but why ?
//        
//        try {
//            instance.save(save);
//            fail("saved stock without storagelocation");
//        } catch (Exception e) {
//            // correct
//            System.out.println("unable to save without storagelocation.");
//        }

    save.setStorageLocation(this.create);
    save.setLastModify(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    instance.save(save);
}

@After
public void cleanUp() {
    this.storageLocationService.delteLocation(create);
}
```

the save method

```
    public void save(final Stock save) {

    try (StatelessSession session = this.hibernateFactory.openStatelessSession()) {
        Transaction beginTransaction = session.beginTransaction();
        beginTransaction.begin();
        if (save.getId() != null) {
            session.update(save);
        } else {
            session.insert(save);
        }
        save.getArticle().setEdited(true);
        session.update(save.getArticle());
        beginTransaction.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        save.setId(null);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Error message:

> org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2182)
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1911)
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:173)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:645)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:495)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:380)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacacom.java:114)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy126.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
>       at org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator.generateHolder(SequenceGenerator.java:116)
>       at org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator.generate(SequenceGenerator.java:109)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.StatelessSessionImpl.insert(StatelessSessionImpl.java:145)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.StatelessSessionImpl.insert(StatelessSessionImpl.java:138)
>       at com.mm.inventur.services.StockService.save(StockService.java:78)
>       at com.mm.inventur.services.StockService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$75cab27c.invoke()
>       at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:669)
>       at com.mm.inventur.services.StockService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5bf3b5b6.save()
>       at com.mm.inventur.services.StockServiceTest.testSave(StockServiceTest.java:84)
>
> testSave(com.mm.inventur.services.StockServiceTest)  Time elapsed: 0.126 sec         <<< ERROR!
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2182)
>       at

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does `instance.save(save);` do?

Comment: All we can say, with what you posted, is that the test most probably fails because instance.save() is supposed to throw an exception, but doesn't.

Comment: added the code of the save method now.

Comment: OK. So what happens when you debug your code. Which lines are being executed?

Comment: As @JBNizet said, even with the code: `save()` should throw an exception but doesn't. Where do you expect it to throw one?

Comment: "There is no error message is just the message of why the code in the try catch failed."  It makes no sense. As a test fails you have either an error (thrown exception) or an assertion failure. Please provide exactly the JUnit message you get.

Comment: i found some error message.